# Can I paginate Facebook FQL queries on the photo table?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have the following FQL:

```
SELECT id, created, like_info, comment_info FROM photo WHERE owner = me()
```

It returns all the information I want in one HTML request and works great.

Except that it only returns the first 100 photos. When I query via the OpenGraph API using `/self/photos/uploaded` and paginate through those results, I properly get the several hundred photos I expect.

The problem is that to get the like and comment info, I have to (potentially) issue several more queries in order to paginate through the comments and likes sections for each photo. As several of these photos have more than 25 comments and more than 25 likes, this can easily add up to several hundred HTTP requests.

I've tried various WHERE clauses in the FQL to get beyond the 100th result returned, but the FQL simply won't return the 101st photo. And, as usual, Facebook's documentation is sorely lacking.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

FQL has `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` keywords, so you could get 100 photos, starting with the 101st by adding `LIMIT 100 OFFSET 101`. I believe you can request up to 5000 items in FQL.

You should look at [FQL Multiqueries](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi) to cut down on the number of calls.